# Why I can't decode and parse user friends in json?

Tags: php, json

Here is code:

```
    <?php
$userFriends = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetFriendList/v0001/?key=[api-key]&steamid=[steam-id]&relationship=all"), true);
foreach ($userFriends->data as $friend) {
    //$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?appid=730&market_hash_name=".rawurlencode($item)), true);
    echo $friend->friends;
}
?>
```

Can't parse. Where problem?

Comment: what do you mean by can't parse ?
What is the value of `$userFriends` ?

Comment: What's the json error (if any)?

Comment: Because `$userFriends` doesn't have a `data` property, it has `friendsList` Also, you specifically ask `json_decode` to return you an array, not an object.

Comment: u should access it like this. $userFriends['friendsList'].

Comment: Ok. Where problem now?
    <?php
    $userFriends = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetFriendList/v0001/?key=786CA495D5CD36D4B653A181136C283E&steamid=76561197960435530&relationship=all"), true);

    foreach ($userFriends['friendsList'] as $friend) {
        //$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?appid=730&market_hash_name=".rawurlencode($item)), true);
        echo $friend->friends;
    }

    ?>

Comment: @M.Dmitriev You should remove your actual API keys from your post.

Comment: var_dump the variable $userFriends. Is it null? Then probably the json string you are getting back isn't valid.

Comment: Your question has been edited by @James to remove the keys, which is good. And I have done the same for the answer which copied your keys from your post. But you really should flag your post with a custom flag for a moderator, to enlist their help in purging the keys from the edit histories completely. Either that, or contact Steam operations and have them revoke the keys and issue you new ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you want access to JSON data with oo `->` syntax, you have to remove `True` parameter from `json_decode`:

```
$userFriends = json_decode( file_get_contents( ... ), true );
```

Then, your JSON has this structure:

```
{
    "friendslist": {
        "friends": [
            {
                "steamid": "0123456789",
                "relationship": "friend",
                "friend_since": 0
            },
            (...)
        ]

    }
}
```

So, to access to friends, you have to write something like this:

```
foreach( $userFriends->friendslist->friends as $friend )
{
    echo $friend->steamid . PHP_EOL;
    echo $friend->relationship . PHP_EOL;
    echo $friend->friend_since . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get the last JSON error in case there was one.  Of course, just echo the error instead of using my exact code.

```
    switch (json_last_error()) {
        case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
            //echo ' - No errors';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
            header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"].'500 Maximum stack depth exceeded');
            $this->response = array('error' => 'JSON Decode error - Maximum stack depth exceeded');
            return $this->return_response();
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH:
            header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"].'500 Underflow or the modes mismatch');
            $this->response = array('error' => 'JSON Decode error - Underflow or the modes mismatch');
            return $this->return_response();
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
            header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"].'500 Unexpected control character found');
            $this->response = array('error' => 'JSON Decode error - Unexpected control character found');
            return $this->return_response();
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
            header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"].'500 Syntax error, malformed JSON');
            $this->response = array('error' => 'JSON Decode error - Syntax error, malformed JSON');
            return $this->return_response();
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_UTF8:
            header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"].'500 Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded');
            $this->response = array('error' => 'JSON Decode error - Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded');
            return $this->return_response();
        break;
        default:
            header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"].'500 Unknown JSON Decode error');
            $this->response = array('error' => 'JSON Decode error - Unknown error');
            return $this->return_response();
        break;
    }
```

Comment: No answer. Error: 


Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\OpenServer\domains\localhost\index.php on line 75

Comment: Then there was no error in decoding the JSON.  I see a comment on your original post that looks like it's your answer though.  If not, please supply the JSON, and also the decoded JSON array.

Answer (score 0):

Can read it as an array

```
<?php
$userFriends = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetFriendList/v0001/?key=[api-key]&steamid=[steam-id]&relationship=all"), true);

foreach ($userFriends['friendslist']['friends'] as $friend) {
    echo $friend['steamid'];
    echo $friend['relationship'];
    echo $friend['friend_since'];
}
?>
```